# How to install gtk-cffi in Windows?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, asdf

[gtk-cffi](http://www.cliki.net/gtk-cffi) is a Lisp binding of GTK+3. I'm trying to install it on Windows.

At first I tried Quicklisp but it didn't have it (there is gtk-cffi-utils, but it didn't help at all). I want to install it from scratch but I don't know what to do...

Is there anybody who can give me some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the page for [gtk-cffi](http://common-lisp.net/project/gtk-cffi/), I see that it depends on:

- CFFI
- Alexandria
- Iterate
- cl-cairo2

I *believe* these are all available through quicklisp, so I am going to assume that you can get all of them.

Looks like for gtk-cffi there are no official releases, and you have to pull it from CVS.  So if you were to checkout the gtk-cffi repository to some directory, say "c:/gtk-cffi", it should be possible for you to start up lisp, make sure that ASDF can load quicklisp systems (including the above dependencies), do:

```
(push "c:/gtk-cffi/" asdf:*central-registry*) ;; change the pathname as needed, but be sure to end with "/"
(asdf:load-system "gtk-cffi")
```